# Reducing CPU Load on a remote select from a database

Tags: c#, odbc, cpu, cpu-usage

I am remotely selecting results from a custom production database with a criteria of around three minutes from a C# application.

Every time the select command is executed, the server PC that I am using CPU goes up to around 50%. But surely, the load should be on the database that I am connecting to?

Why would the C# application rocket to 50% until the data is retrieved for reading?

**Some background**

- I have worked out from debugging that the Select statement on the
  remote database takes around 30-40 seconds, baring in mind I am selecting   with a criteria that uses the indexed column.
- At the same time of selecting data from the remote DB, I have monitored the TaskManager and the CPU sits at 50% until the select as complete.. this can last around 30-40 seconds each loop.
- If I select in the native sql engine for the remote DB, there is no lag on the select, the data (if any) is returned immediately.
- I know its not the parsing of result set that is taking up the CPU load as some selects will return nothing.

Here is some code I am using.

```
OdbcConnection remoteConn = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["remoteConnectionString"].ToString());

            remoteConn.Open();

            OdbcCommand remoteCommand = new OdbcCommand();
            remoteCommand.Connection = remoteConn;

            using (remoteConn)
            {
                string localSql = "";
                string remoteSql = "select * from tracking where last_update > 212316247440000000"; // Julian No = 2015-07-12 11:24:00

                remoteCommand.CommandText = remoteSql;

                OdbcDataReader remoteReader;

                remoteReader = remoteCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (remoteReader.Read())
                {


                    for (int i = 0; i < 68; i++)
                    {
                        localSql += ",'" + remoteReader[i].ToString() + "'";
                    }

                }

            }
```

I ran a performance and diagnostic test on the application and it yielded this result.

[image]

How, if any, can I reduce this CPU load or even eradicate it completely. It is completely out of the ordinary and I have no clue on how to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: A few questions before I suggest a solution... I see you are using the ODBC drivers, but what type of database are you connecting to? How many rows are being returned from the query? Do you need all 68 columns? Finally, can you provide some context as to where this code is executing? Is executing in a GUI application? If so, is executing on the main thread?

Comment: @Randy - 1. It is an SQL DB. 2. Sometimes around ten rows.. sometimes none. 3. Yes all columns are needed. 4. Its executed in a windows forms application. I have tried it on the main thread and on background worker, no difference at all. EDIT: and I have also tried it in a console application, no difference again - Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the information, Dan. Here are my thoughts...

**I believe the primary reason why your app is consuming so much CPU is because of the drivers you are using.**

Since you are connecting to an SQL Server database, you should use the SQL Server drivers which know how to optimize transportation of data between client and server.

To use the appropriate drivers, make sure you use the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc.

This will allow SQL Server to *stream* the results to your client as you query the data reader.

Secondly, do not use the `ExecuteReader()` method on the `DbCommand` object. One of the many wonderful features unique to the SQL Server drivers is the `ExecuteReaderAsync()` method.

Since this command is an IO-bound operation (not compute-bound) then there is no need to block the calling thread. When the result come back they will arrive on an IO completion thread.

Here is a code sample of what your code might look like after the change.

```
using (var remoteConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["remoteConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    remoteConn.Open();
    using (var remoteCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        remoteCommand.Connection = remoteConn;
        string localSql = "";
        string remoteSql = "select * from tracking where last_update > 212316247440000000"; // Julian No = 2015-07-12 11:24:00

        remoteCommand.CommandText = remoteSql;
        var remoteReader = await remoteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (remoteReader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 68; i++)
            {
                localSql += ",'" + remoteReader[i].ToString() + "'";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to provide an example of what the solution might look like.

Comment: You mentioned "optimize transportation of data", but sometimes there is no return In data. It's just a select on the DB that returns nothing, would this still be a driver issue?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know what the ODBC drivers are doing under the hood but I can say that they are very generic and don't leverage the technologies that Microsoft has set forth in the SQL Server drivers to optimize query execution against a SQL Server database. Did you notice an improvement in performance when you switched to the SQL Server drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the select command is run from a separate computer than the one hosting the SQL DB.

Frankly it is a bit baffling. The only thing that comes to my mind is that it might be taking time passing and processing the metadata. Have you tried changing your query to return say only one piece of data?

For example:

```
select top 1 last_update from tracking where last_update > 212316247440000000
select count (*) from tracking where last_update > 212316247440000000
```

This will clarify if the data+metadata is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be parsing of the result? Are you using some sort of datalayer that automatically parse resultsets into domain objects? That could be very CPU intense..

Comment: I don't think so as the application I have loops every thirty seconds, 7 times out of ten loops there usually isn't any new data, but the CPU still rockets to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for your `IO Bound` operations is using the `Task`, becouse it does not need to change existing code:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    //your code or @Randy code with little change here:
    using (var remoteConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["remoteConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        remoteConn.Open();
        using (var remoteCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            remoteCommand.Connection = remoteConn;
            string localSql = "";
            string remoteSql = "select * from tracking where last_update > 212316247440000000"; // Julian No = 2015-07-12 11:24:00

            remoteCommand.CommandText = remoteSql;
            var remoteReader = remoteCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (remoteReader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 68; i++)
                {
                    localSql += ",'" + remoteReader[i].ToString() + "'";
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
//use can use 'task.wait();' to waiting for complete the task.
```

Comment: Actually this is slightly incorrect as the thread the task is executed on would still be blocked by the IO bound operation ExecuteReader().